# re-declaring arguments variable doesn't throw any error - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, arguments, local-variables

Reading the docs about [the `arguments` object at mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments#Description).

> The `arguments` object is a local variable available within all non-arrow functions. You can refer to a function's arguments inside that function by using its arguments object.

It says the `arguments` is a **local variable**, but if I re-declare it using `let/const`, no error is thrown, unlike the ordinary ones.

```
function fn(arg1) {
  // let arg1 = []; // Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'arg1' has already been declared
  let arguments = []; // array or whatever, no error
}
```

So my question is why doesn't re-declaring `arguments` variable throw any error?

Answer (score 0):

In strict mode, it is a syntax error to use `arguments` (or `eval`) as a variable name:

```
function fn(arg1) {
  "use strict";
  let arguments;
}
```

In sloppy mode, you're just <s>shadowing</s> replacing the implicit variable with a `let`, `function`, or parameter declaration. If you create your own variable with the name `arguments`, the Arguments object is not created at all so that it doesn't collide with your code. It's **not a re-declaration** of a `var arguments` - the implicit `arguments` variable is created conditionally.

Still, if you explicitly write `var arguments`, that doesn't count to prevent the implicit creation, but doesn't overwrite it either.

Comment: if it's already a local variable of the function, how can it be shadowed? I mean it might make sense if the `arguments` was declared in outer scope, isn't this the case?

Comment: I checked and "shadowing" is the wrong term here.